# When using a header only in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, math, header

is it usual to use for a class like "vec3" only a header?

This is my actual code:

```
#ifndef VECTOR3_H
#define VECTOR3_H

#include <math.h>

class vec3
{
public:
    double x, y, z;
    vec3();
    vec3(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    double lenght()
    { return sqrt(pow(x, 2) * pow(y, 2) * pow(z, 2));}
    double lenghtSquared()
    { return pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2);}
    double distance(vec3 v)
    { return sqrt(pow(x - v.x, 2) * pow(y - v.y, 2) * pow(z - v.z, 2));}
    double distanceSquared(vec3 v)
    { return pow(x - v.x, 2) + pow(y - v.y, 2) + pow(z - v.z, 2);}
    float angle(vec3 v)
    { return (float) acos(dot(v) / lenght() * v.lenght());}
    double dot(vec3 v)
    { return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;}
    void cross(vec3 v) {
        double a = y * v.z - v.y * z; double b = z * v.x - v.z * x;
        double c = x * v.y - v.x * y; x = a; y = b; z = c;}
    void normalize()
    { x, y, z /= lenght();}
};

#endif // VECTOR3_H
```

Can I better create also a source file instead of only a header?
If you have some tips, I like them :)

Thanks in advance

***EDIT: And what means inline exactly?***

Comment: All the functions are simple, so there's no use in having them in a separate source file. Header-only "libraries" is okay, much of the standard library is header-only.

Comment: Templates basically require it. Having non-templates as header only occurs less often, but it does happen. With such simple, short functions, there's really no problem leaving it like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class definition needs to go in a header, if you want it to be generally usable. If it's in a source file, then it's only available within that source file, not in others.

The member function definitions can either be inline like yours are; or you could move them to a source file, leaving just declarations in the class.

There are pros and cons to both approaches. A header-only implementation is easier to share and distribute, and offers more optimisation opportunities since the functions are easier to inline; but can lead to longer build times if there are a lot of large functions included in many translation unit, and makes the header more cluttered if you want to use it as "documentation" for the class interface.

> And what means inline exactly?

It means a function is either defined inside a class, or declared `inline`. In either case, its purpose is to relax the "One Definition Rule", so that you are allowed to define the function in more than one translation unit; and it *must* be defined in every unit in which it's used. This is necessary if you want the definition to appear in a header (which may be included from multiple units). It gives the compiler a better opportunity to inline function calls, replacing them with the body of the function to avoid the cost of the calls.

Comment: Thank you :) But if I use the prefix "inline" before a method, what is the difference then?

Comment: @RandomUser: I've just added a description of what "inline" means.

Comment: So, if I understand it: I can create a function everywhere my header is called?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing unusual about that, no.  In some cases (eg. templates) it's actually required.

In practice, putting the member definitions in a `cpp` file can make the code easier to manage, and can make building your project faster, but in this case there's so little code that it won't make any difference.

Comment: well actually, if that header is being included in many compilation units, it will make a difference no matter how small that header itself is.