# C++ template with no template parameters?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11

I hate the boilerplate and Don't Repeat Yourself violations inherent in traditional class declarations in C++.

Is it possible to create a template with no template parameters, purely to enable the class to be defined in a header file without violating the One Definition Rule, in C++11?

Comment: what would be the point? If what you're wanting is to declare & implement a class entirely in the header, you can do that without it being a template. Note however that every module that includes that header will get a copy of that implementation and you may get "duplicate symbol" linker errors.

Comment: this is called a [header only library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only) and there are [no templates required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441036/when-using-a-header-only-in-c-c).

Comment: I think the One Definition Rule is not as restrictive as you seem to think.

Comment: Is writing `inline` really such a burden?

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method?lq=1). Best explanation I've ever seen anywhere.

Comment: I'm still learning about how classes affect linkage, figuring out what the status quo is, and deciding whether or not to fight it by writing in a functional style, i.e. returning tuples to mimic patterns from Rust and Haskell.

Comment: @AndrewWagner, good luck with that. You might be better off just really learning C++ really well and do things the C++ way. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for templates whatsoever.

If you want to write a header-only class, all you have to do is mark `inline` the functions that will be defined external to the class declaration:

```
#pragma once

struct some_class {
    void implicitly_inline() { ... }

    inline void explicitly_inline();
};

void some_class::explicitly_inline() { ... }
```

The occasional extra `inline` keyword is hardly such a burden as to change the entire definition of your class.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a template with no template parameters

No. And you don't need for such workaround because...

> to enable the class to be defined in a header file without violating the One Definition Rule

You can define a class in a header file without violating the One Definition Rule.

You can even define the member functions of a class in a header - which I think is the point of this question. Simply declare them all [inline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). If you define the member functions within the class definition, then they're implicitly inline.

> There may be more than one definition of an inline function in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit. For example, an inline function may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, the re-compile my class every time I #include it, but the linker will merge the redundant instances?  And I should pray that my build is configured properly so that old .o files don't stick around...

Comment: @AndrewWagner A compiler may skip re-compiling if it has such optimization, but in principle, yes. There are similarities in linking templates inlines.